# Work with action from another ORGANIZATION

Tags: github, workflow, github-actions

How to assign github action from another ORGANIZATION, that doesn't load to marketplace?
What do I write in my workflow file?
I see information only the same ORGANIZATION, but no different.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the repository containing the action is public and contains an `action.yaml` or `action.yml` at the repository root, you can access it with the `- uses: orgname/repo@sha` where `sha` can be the commit hash, version tag, or branch name ref. It does not need to be published to the Marketplace.

This is answered on the GitHub community forums [here](https://github.community/t/is-it-possible-to-test-a-github-action-without-publishing-it-on-marketplace/128306/2).